# Convert Ruby Code To PHP Help Please

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby Code:

```
  # Turn hash input into JSON, store it in variable called "my_input"
my_input = { "itemFilter" => { "keywords" => "milk" }}.to_json 
  # Open connection to website.com
@http = Net::HTTP.new("website.com")
  # Post the request to our API, with the "findItems" name and our JSON from above as the value
response_code, data = @http.post("/requests", "findItems=#{my_input}", 
                                 {'X-CUSTOM-HEADER' => 'MYCUSTOMCODE'}) 
my_hash = Crack::JSON.parse(data)
my_milk = my_hash["findItems"]["item"].first
```

PHP code:

```
$requestBody = json_encode(array("itemFilter" => array( "keywords" => "milk" ))); 
$headers = array ('X-CUSTOM-HEADER: MYCODE'); 
$connection = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'website.com/request/findItems='); 
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody); 
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$response = curl_exec($connection); 
curl_close($connection); 
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Do you want help or do you want someone to write the entire thing for you?

Comment: We will help you with your problems, but we will not do your job for you. Show us that you put some effort into this, and we'll help you the rest of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem..  Thanks for the input.  I put a trailing slash where it was not required, and the json_encode was putting brackets around the encoding, and it didn't need them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode), [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) and the [cURL](http://php.net/curl) extension.

Comment: This is what I've got so far.
$requestBody =json_encode(array("itemFilter" => array( "keywords" => "milk" )));
$headers = array ('X-CUSTOM-HEADER: MYCODE');
$connection = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.website.com/request/findItems=');
      curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
      curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      $response = curl_exec($connection);
      curl_close($connection);
print_r($connect

Comment: It doesn't work..  I'm guessing I'm going the URL or POST fields wrong, because it sees my custom header code just fine.

Comment: Edit your question; add your code, the expected result and actual result.  Indent each line of code with 4 spaces to format it as code.